# How come some of my questions get only some comments but not any answer?

Tags: discussion, comment, answers, asking-questions, community

Certain times, I post questions that get some valuable comments but never an answer.
For example the question for [comparison on real numbers](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4286364/correct-comparison-of-real-number-for-n-digits-precision-absolute-vs-relative-d) and caveats.

I am not sure why this happening. Is my post not clear? Is it too trivial to be answered? Is it a bad/non sense question? Something else that I am not aware about this site on stackexchange?

If you have some feedback I would be happy to hear it to get better at my posts.

Comment: I suspect that some people might think your comparison question is more about program code than about maths, and so they aren't interested.

Comment: Why the downvotes?

Comment: If you encounter helpful comments, I'd encourage *you* to encourage the helpful commenter to make an answer based on the comment, and/or, to make an answer of the comment and expand a bit.  Many comments are from users who want to be helpful, me included, but may be unsure of what you exactly seek in your question.  When someone hits on something you find helpful, since you are a participant in the Q&A interaction, you'd be wise to let a commenter know that.

Comment: @Jim  re: downvotes  Meta is different than main.  Here some users may downvote if your question strikes them as a complaint, or some other reason.  I can understand your asking "what's up with that", but some might wonder "at least you get comments; I don't even get comments on my questions!"  I.e., downvotes don't reflect the quality of your question or anyone's question on meta (usually).

Comment: But if this post is based primarily on the outcome of the post you linked here, then I agree with @PeterPhipps.

Comment: I suggested that some users might comment instead of posting answers for fear of running afoul of the EoQS – my comment had a dozen upvotes – now my comment has been disappeared.